# image % height dimensions not being adhered to in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've got an `img` in a `td` with both `width` and `height` set to `100%`. In Chrome The `width` is obeyed to but the `height` is not. It seems to work as expected in all the other browsers.

Not sure why?

```css
div
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

table
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I was able to get it to work by wrapping the `img` in a `div`.

```css
div.one
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

table
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set a **max-height** or **max-width** to avoid an inner element to extend beyond the outter element.

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div
{
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Remember to remove all margin and padding to the table.

Comment: Mind updating this fiddle to show me what you mean? I tried what you have but that did not work. http://jsfiddle.net/imthenachoman/kv4zpkuu/1/

Comment: Ok, updated in the Fiddle. It required a div wrapper around the image.

Comment: Thanks! I actually got it to work by wrapping the `img` in a `div`.

Comment: Glad it could be useful! Please remember to mark the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the table. The image is setting its height to 100% of its container, the issue is the td is getting its height from the images original height (190px). My recommendation would be to get rid of the table all together, just put the image in the div and it will work flawlessly. Otherwise you'll need to set the td height to 100px.

perhaps this looks close enough to what you wanted : http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/kv4zpkuu/6/

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

div img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    border: 4px ridge;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I actually got it to work by wrapping the `img` in a `div`.